# query to get records with exact values of a field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table like this:

```
id_doc | id_category
1        a
1        c
1        f
2        a
2        g
3        a
3        b
3        f
4        h
```

I need a query to extract docs that have categories  "a" and "f".

example:

```
id_doc
1
3
```

please help me!
Thanks

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate and use `HAVING` to check if the number of distinct groups a document is in equals 2.

```
SELECT id_doc
       FROM document_category
       WHERE id_category IN ('a',
                             'f')
       GROUP BY id_doc
       HAVING count(DISTINCT id_category) = 2;
```

Or, if you have a documents table use two `EXISTS`.

```
SELECT d.id_doc
       FROM document d
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM document_category dc
                            WHERE dc.id_doc = d.id_doc
                                  AND dc.id_category = 'a')
             AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM document_category dc
                                WHERE dc.id_doc = d.id_doc
                                      AND dc.id_category = 'f');
```

Comment: Exactly, it works ! Thank you so much